# Change Document 'objects' property to 'query'

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb-query, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to change the document 'objects' property to 'query'. It's more intuitive since one is querying the database.
Like;
`Collection.query.find()`
Instead of;
`Collection.objects.find()`
I have tried setting a query attribute to my Collection model like;

```
class Collection(Document):
    def __setattr__(self, key, objects):
        self.__dict__['query'] = self.objects
```

But on checking the type it returns a class of the QueryManager instead of Queryset  like;

```
>>>print(type(Collection.query))
<'class' mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QueryManager >
```

Instead of;

```
>>>print(type(Collection.query))
<'class' mongoengine.queryset.queryset.Queryset >
```

Could someone offer a solution ?

Comment: Try `Collection.query.get(params = 'params')` , this will fetch you the data for that particular parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an abstract Document class and within it define a custom QuerySet manager using queryset_manager wrapper. Inherit the abstract class as a Base class for all other subsequent Document classes.

```
from mongoengine.document import Document
from mongoengine.queryset import queryset_manager

class BaseDocument(Document):
    meta = {'abstract': True}
    @queryset_manager
    def query(self, queryset):
        return queryset

class Foo(BaseDocument):
    ...
```

To query use `Foo.query.*` which is more intuitive 
instead of the default `Foo.objects.*`.
Displaying the type will return `<class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.Queryset'>` as expected.